# Too much time to train one epoch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-dataloader

I use an RTX 3060 12GB GPU enabled workstation with RAM of 16GB DDR4 and CPU Intel Core i5 10400F. Also mounted an external storage HDD drive and ran the script p2ch11.prepcache from the bellow referred repository in order to cache… Used from zero to 8 workers and various batch size selections ranging from 32 to 1024!! Still it takes approximately 13,5 hours to train for one epoch (with batch size=1024 and 4 workers!!)… I still haven’t figured what’s wrong… Looks like I cannot utilize the GPU for some reason …

Code pulled from the repository: https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code
-> p2ch11.training.py (https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/blob/master/p2ch11/training.py)

Comment: Can you provide more information. What dataset, data you are using. What post processing, augmentation you are maybe doing. Did you look at your RAM, maybe you write in a swap file. Can you let the data loader run "dry", so just looping over it and measure the time.

Comment: It is the LUng Nodule Analysis 2016 (LUNA 2016) dataset (https://luna16.grand-challenge.org/) with 551.065 samples. The dataset and the code is stored in external storage device (HHD) that is mounted  as NTFS folders in my PC. No image augmentation process was performed. It seems that my RAM is not utilized appropriately. Perhaps I do write in a swap file (however, I must admit, that can not understand what it means!!). I will follow your advice and just loop over the dataloader and time it and report the results. Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The size of an image is large, you need to do some preprocessing first. I think [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/arnavkj95/candidate-generation-and-luna16-preprocessing/notebook) will help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just follow the approach of the book “Deep Learning with PyTorch” to figure out how deep learning with PyTorch actually works on real-life projects as detecting suspected tumors from CT scans (code: https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).